# Count(*) won't display when result is 0 when using group by

Tags: mysql

Sorry I couldn't think of a better title...

So I have this database where I have a table 'bibitems' (basicly texts) 'tags' (the tags the text is filed under) and 'taglinks' (Associative entity between a bibitem and a tag)

So on my page I want to display every tag, directly followed by the amount of documents that are filed under that tag
so if 2 documents are under 'java' it's say 
java (2)

```
SELECT
    tags.id,
    naamnl,
    COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM
    tags, 
    bibitems, 
    taglinks
WHERE
    bibitems.id=taglinks.item_id 
    AND tag_id=tags.id
GROUP BY
    naamnl
```

This works well when there are documents filed under a certain tag.
But when there's a tag that's unused so far, it won't pop up.

I want it to display java (0) in that case

Comment: First google hit: http://lichao.net/eblog/how-to-display-0-in-conditional-group-by-report-in-count-sql-query-200808164.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tags.id,
       tags.naamnl,
       COUNT(bibitems.id) AS 'count'
  FROM tags
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN taglinks
    ON taglinks.tag_id = tags.id
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN bibitems
    ON bibitems.id = taglinks.item_id
 GROUP
    BY tags.id,
       tags.naamnl
;
```

or

```
SELECT tags.id,
       tags.naamnl,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM bibitems
          WHERE bibitems.id IN
                 ( SELECT taglinks.item_id
                     FROM taglinks
                    WHERE taglinks.tag_id = tags.id
                 )
       )
  FROM tags
 GROUP
    BY tags.id,
       tags.naamnl
;
```

(Take your pick.)

Answer (score 1):

Read on the difference between INNER and OUTER joins.

```
SELECT tag.id, naamnl, COUNT(taglink.tag_id) AS 'count' 
FROM tag
LEFT OUTER JOIN taglink ON taglink.tag_id=tag.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bibitem ON bibitem.id=taglink.item_id 
GROUP BY tag.id, naamnl
```

Comment: Have you tested that? Because I'm pretty sure that the `COUNT(*)` will evaluate to one when the OP wants it to evaluate to zero. Won't it?

Comment: The singular vs plural naming convention is based on opinion and personal style. Either convention is acceptable.

Comment: ruakh is correct. The count of the tags will have to be done as a nested query and then joined back.

Comment: You probably don't need a nested query... Just turn the NULL into a 0 with ifnull()

Comment: Fixed with IFNULL (still haven't tested though, don't have MySQL here); also removed subjective thing about plural/singular, though I do feel pretty strongly about it.

Comment: The new version has the same problem. It's actually almost the exact opposite of the right fix: `COUNT()` counts the non-null values, so `COUNT(0)` is the same as `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Argh, SQL (or I?) sucks.  How about now?

Comment: @MK: Yup, I think you're good now. (Personally I prefer to use `COUNT` to count non-null values, but you're not alone in preferring to translate null/non-null to zero/one and using `SUM`.)

Comment: I actually changed it back to COUNT now that I understand how it works.  It is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like thisshould do it. (It is difficult since you did not provide the full table schemas.)

```
SELECT
   i.naamnl,
   COALESCE(t.Count, 0)      AS Count
FROM
   bibitems i
LEFT JOIN
   (
      SELECT
         tag_id,
         COUNT(*) AS Count
      FROM
         taglinks
      GROUP BY
         item_id
   ) t
 ON
    t.tag_id = i.tag_id
```